# How to keep escape characters in xml text with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am processing xml document with BeautifulSoup.  I would need to maintain all the escape characters of tag strings, but BeautifulSoup converts the escape characters to special characters.

If I create a BeautifulSoup object with following string

```
<mytext>
            &lt;p&gt;MyText&lt;/p&gt;
</myext>
```

and get the text out of  tag using **.text** property I get below string

```
<p>MyText</p&>
```

but I need to maintain the original form of the string.  How can I stop BeautifulSoup processing these special characters?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to keep the html entity notation by using

```
soup.prettify(formatter='html')
```

and

```
str(soup)
```

notations.

Thought somebody else might need this information.